# Need help vectorizing a double for-loop creating a matrix of norms of vector differences in R

Tags: r, vectorization

I'm trying to figure out how to vectorize the following code block in R:

X is an N x M matrix

centers is a K x M matrix

```
  phi <- matrix(0, nrow(X), nrow(centers))
  for(i in 1:nrow(phi)) {
    for(j in 1:ncol(phi)) {
      phi[i, j] <- norm(as.matrix(X[i, ]) - as.matrix(centers[j, ]), type = 'F')
    }
  }
```

I'm constructing an N x K matrix, phi, which at each position, [i, j], contains the norm of the difference between the vectors at row i of X and row j of centers:

phi[i, j] = || X[i, ] - centers[j, ] ||

My approach so far has been to attempt to use R's outer() function.  I'm new to the outer() function, so I've searched for several examples, however, the examples I've come across involve using outer() to apply some function to a pair of vectors of scalar values.  As I'm dealing with the differences between pairs of rows from two matrices, outer() behaves different than expected.  I'm not sure how to get it to recognize the matrices I'm passing it (X and centers) as vectors of vectors, where each row represents a vector to be involved in the computation of phi.

In addition, when I define a function to compute the norm of the difference between two M-length vectors, that function returns a scalar.  It is my understanding that in order to vectorize a function using R's Vectorize(), that function must return a result of the same length as its arguments.  I'm not sure how to define a function which, when used in conjunction with outer(), recognizes each row of a matrix as a single element (in spite of it being an M-length vector).

Below are a couple of my attempts to use outer() with toy examples of the matrices X and centers.

```
X <- matrix(c(7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6), 3, 3)
centers <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 2, 3)
fun <- function(y, x) norm(as.matrix(y) - as.matrix(x), type = 'F')
outer(X, centers, fun)
```

This was my first attempt.  I was trying to use outer() in a manner analogous to the way it is used when it is passed a pair of vectors.  I was (naively) hoping it would take one row from each matrix at a time, pass them as the two arguments to fun, and position the result appropriately in the product matrix.  Instead, I get the following error message.

```
Error in outer(X, centers, fun) : 
  dims [product 54] do not match the length of object [1]
```

I also tried vectorizing my function using R's Vectorize() before calling outer().

```
Vecfun <- Vectorize(fun)
outer(X, centers, Vecfun)
```

In this case, I no longer get an error message, but the result is an erroneous matrix of matrices.  I'm also new to the Vectorize() function, so I'm not too sure why it produces the result that it does as I don't have a real grasp on what it does; using it was sort of a shot in the dark.

I'll appreciate any help in vectorizing my original problem; I'm completely open to suggestions that do not involve outer().

Clarifications regarding outer() and Vectorize() also welcome.

Comment: Your "X", and "Y" in `outer` could be the `1:nrow(X)` and `1:nrow(centers)`; "fun", then, would be `..as.matrix(X[y, ]) - as.matrix(centers[x, ])..`

Comment: You would need to spell "FUN" correctly, though.

Comment: @alexis_laz Your suggestion is exactly what I needed; thank you so much.